# Remove entries based on group by

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
venue_id,latitude,longitude,venue_category,country_code,user_id,uct_time,time_offset
4af833a6f964a5205a0b22e3,13.693775,100.751152,Airport,TH,4337,Tue Apr 03 20:35:48 +0000 2012,420
4af833a6f964a5205a0b22e3,13.693775,100.751152,Airport,TH,101773,Tue Apr 03 20:46:53 +0000 2012,420
4af833a6f964a5205a0b22e3,13.693775,100.751152,Airport,TH,105093,Tue Apr 03 22:39:56 +0000 2012,420
4af833a6f964a5205a0b22e3,13.693775,100.751152,Airport,TH,58835,Tue Apr 03 22:54:52 +0000 2012,420
....
```

and I need to remove the venue_id that have less than 100 occurrences.

I have tried to use the following code:

```
joined = joined[joined.groupby("venue_id").venue_id.transform(len) >= 100]
```

which is inspired by the answer from the question with ID 13446480.

The problem is that it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'venue_id'
```

Please bear in mind that I new to Pandas and I want to learn, so if you could give some explanation as well I would be grateful.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ?

Comment: @jezrael I have solved the problem with your first suggestion

Comment: Supeeer, glad can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems first column is index, so help [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

So need:

```
joined = joined.reset_index()
joined = joined[joined.groupby("venue_id")['venue_id'].transform(len) >= 100]
```

Also for me works if first column is index and dont need `reset_index`:

```
joined = joined[joined.groupby("venue_id").transform(len) >= 100]
```

If dont use last versions of pandas (`0.20.1`) then is necessary add some column:

```
joined = joined[joined.groupby(level="venue_id")['latitude'].transform(len) >= 100]
```

EDIT1:

[Faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44322390/2901002) is use `size` as `len`.

```
joined = joined[joined.groupby("venue_id")['latitude'].transform('size') >= 100]
```